# Has there been a rise of flat-Earthers?

Tags: earth

From [this tweet](https://twitter.com/neiltyson/status/1111295662920888320) by Neil deGrasse Tyson:

> The rise of flat-Earthers in the United States...

And from [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2019/feb/17/study-blames-youtube-for-rise-in-number-of-flat-earthers)

> Researchers believe they have identified the prime driver for a startling rise in the number of people who think the Earth is flat...

**Is there a rise in the number of people who think the Earth is flat?**

I found this [YouGov article](https://today.yougov.com/topics/philosophy/articles-reports/2018/04/02/most-flat-earthers-consider-themselves-religious) which states "Just 66% of millennials firmly believe that the earth is round." The same article shows that a higher percentage of respondents believe the Earth is round with an increasing age group. However, YouGov doesn't publicly release its methodology, so I am not particularly inclined to believe its results (especially if uncorroborated).

I have also seen the graph below. However, it indicates (supposedly) search volume, which may not be proportional to the number of flat-Earthers (i.e. if I search "Flat earth," it doesn't necessarily mean I am a flat-Earther).

[image]

Note: The tweet mentions "in the United States." This question relates to people in general as in the entire Earth population.

Comment: Your last point is very relevant. Google trends or any other traffic metrics don't mean that there are more believers, just that it's a trendy topic. This exact question for example, increase traffic about flat earth topic, without claiming it's true

Comment: As for your final Note, that most probably makes the question unanswerable, there are unlikely to exist any worldwide representative surveys with this question, that have been consistently asked over time.  If you limit it to the USA then it *may* be answerable (or not).  Also, the tweet by Neil deGrasse Tyson makes the claim only for the USA.

Comment: I think you could definitely say that there's an obvious rise in the _visibility_ of the flat-Earth movement; but beyond that would be rather difficult to determine.  It seems unlikely you will find statistics for the number of "flat-Earthers" over time.  There's also the issue of Poe's Law.  Even looking at the numbers of Youtube videos, or Facebook groups supporting the topic, it's not clear how many of those people are being satirical.  I think people are a lot more aware of the movement in the internet age; but if they're anything like me, people looking up "flat Earth" don't support it.

Comment: @JMac Or enjoy arguing for a flat earth just to make everyone else frustrated.

Comment: @JMac There are polls of public support for various conspiracy theories over time. Of course some people might still answer anonymous polls dishonestly for a laugh, but that's something the pollsters usually try to account for

Comment: @gerrit Your comment, while insightful, may not be 100% accurate. "Also, the tweet by Neil deGrasse Tyson makes the claim only for the USA." This may not be the case. Search Google for "rise in flat-Earthers" and you will see many *general* claims that don't restrict the phenomenon to the US. In addition, Tyson won't be in any top search result. Why did I even include his tweet in the question? Because its why I got curious.

Comment: I am a fan of the title of that chart: "Spheres of influence".

Comment: statistics can be very misleading, saying something like the rise in flat-Earthers could refer to a numerical count rather than a percentage where the numeric count has increased but the percentage of believers has decreased. This sort of misleading statistic could easily be true given population growth.

Comment: A rise of flat-Earthers?  Well, there's been a [rise of at least one flat-Earther](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2018/03/25/flat-earther-blasts-california-sky-homemade-steam-powered-rocket/), to an altitude of 1875 feet.

Comment: @Mark The joke! Very nice.

Comment: @Ertai87 Introducing "Spheres of influence": Graph created by a round-Earther. :)

Comment: @BKlassen I agree with your point. It will be ideal if the statistic included in the answer contains both absolute number of flat-Earthers as well as the percentage of flat-Earthers.

Comment: @JMac RE your comment, did you look up "flat Earth?"

Comment: @Mark From the article, the flat-Earther says, *"The problem is, it brings out all the nuts also"*, now I don't know anymore if it's satire or not.

Comment: "Just 66% of millennials firmly believe that the earth is round" Sounds a lot to me like "44% of teenagers take the piss out of dumb survey"

Comment: @Jon.G 33% or 44%?

Comment: @BarryHarrison I could try and style that out as intentional but no, just bad at maths apparently

Comment: @Jon.G OK, then the comment makes sense :) I appreciate the humor.

Comment: @Jon Millennials are not teenagers at this point. I'm a millennial (at the edge) and I'm 33. I think 23 years old is the current power limit.

Comment: This [Scientific American article](https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/observations/do-people-really-think-earth-might-be-flat/) reviewed the YouGov data and determined that the 66% figure was not reproducible, and instead came up with a figure of 82.5%.